# Tensorflow_docs not showing up in environment's install window

Tags: python, pip, installation, conda, environment

I want to import tensorflow_docs in a **PyCharm** python file. The I've installed it by

`pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

In PyCharm, the interpreter's install window does not contain tensorflow_docs as a package. I tried

`conda install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

At first, attempting to install tensorflow_docs gave the readout:

> "Requirement already installed in anaconda/..."

I uninstalled with `pip` and reinstalled from `github`, but it still won't show up in **PyCharm**.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution and just an idea, but try creating a new environment so there is a fresh state to build on top.